# Не отображается изображение кнопки

Tags: android-studio

[image: Что не так ?]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="119dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="119dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="119dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_1"
    android:src="@drawable/elipse"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</ImageButton>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Соответствующий activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton button_1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Ошибок не показывает 

    button_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button_1.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
}

При этом приложение падает
```

Comment: android:layout_height="1dp" здесь проставьте большее значение

Comment: Да, или `0dp` - тогда оно должно растянуться на весь экран минус марджины